# NavigationBar coincides with status bar when searchDisplayController is activated iOS 7

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uisearchbar, statusbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a tableView controller which has a searchbar added to tableHeaderView. When I click on searchBar it animates to cover the screen. However, the view behind gets adjusted and navigationBar overlaps with status bar as shown below:[image]

It adjusts back fine, when the search is cancelled. How to hold the view at the back of searchDisplayController not to overlap the status bar?

Comment: fixed by doing: [[[parentFileViewController navigationController] navigationBar] setHidden: YES]; in searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch method where parentFileViewController contains the searchBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by doing: [[[parentFileViewController navigationController] navigationBar] setHidden: YES]; in searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch method where parentFileViewController contains the searchBar